# verilog or vhdl source browser like opengrok

Tags: vhdl, verilog, ctags, opengrok

I setup an opengrok instance for our SW team

You might ask: "What is opengrok" -

- It reads your source code -
- It indexes functions variables, etc
- Often these tools use Ctags (but there are other apps)
- And produces clickable HTML versions of your projects source code.

LXR is similar tool but it also does not support vhdl and/or verilog

My ask is this:

- The hardware team said: "cool - can we get this for VHDL or VERILOG?"
- It seems opengrok does not currently support these languages.
- Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, although OpenGrok doesn't support VHDL and VERILOG, you can index repositories with these file types and the search will work correctly the same way. The most of the search features will be available but some (e.g. search for definitions or sintax highlighting) will not.